# How to pass a files/ folder in ansible include_role option

Tags: ansible

I am trying to reuse an existing role by using the `include_role` feature in ansible but I can not seem to find a way to pass the files inside the `files/testrole1.yaml` folder from the calling role and it always uses the files from the common role.
Here is the structure and code I came up with so far:

[image]

```
---
- name: importing tasks from role1
  include_role:
    name: service-deploy-role1
    tasks_from: "{{item}}"
  loop:
       - install
       - setup
```

The above code always uses the `testrole1.yaml file`. Is is possible to pass the `testrole2.yml` when I call the install task from the `service-deploy-role1`?

Answer (score -1):

I could figure out the solution:

```
---
- name: workaround
  set_fact:
    role_location: "{{ role_path }}"

- name: debug role path
  debug:
    msg: "{{ role_location }}"

- name: importing tasks from role1
  include_role:
    name: service-deploy-role1
    tasks_from: "{{item}}"
  vars:
    role_dir: "{{ role_location }}"
  loop:
       - install
       - setup
```